# Limiting number of disqus comments displaying on WordPress post?

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I have disqus comment system plugin installed on self-hosted wordpress website. There is no option to set limit on number of comments displaying on the page/post.

As the number of comments increases it slows down the page. Also the older comments are not required on my site.

Can anyone tell me a way to limit the disqus comments to 10 or 15 on a page and then there can be option to load more.

Comment: This is controlled by Disqus and not Wordpress, and there is no option for that - so this isn't a development question.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus not support disqus_per_page parametres and pagination currently version. Default value 50 comments. I sended mail, i hope will fixed :)